# Connecting to PostgreSQL with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, mac

I can't connect to a local PostGIS database.  My installation is with Mac OS X (10.8), Postgres.app (in doc it's said to have PostGIS included) and Quantum GIS 1.8.

When I want to add a connection to PostgreSQL, I'm specifying name, host (localhost), port (5432), database name, user name and password (service field left empty).

I can connect to a database with Navicat, so database server seems to run correctly.

With the exact information in QGIS used in Navicat, it can't connect... why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, in fact, the problem was PostGIS not *activated* in Postgres.app out of the box.  And when we want to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`, we have this error:

> ERROR:  could not load library "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so": dlopen(/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libgdal.dylib
>     Reason: image not found

It's because the file `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib` is not installed on Mac OS X 10.8 by default.  We can install it with MacBrew using `brew install libjpeg`.

When it's done, we can successfully use the `CREATE EXTENSION` command, as the previous answer suggests:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost dbname -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;'
```

Note: with Postgres.app, the user `postgres` doesn't exist by default, you can use any user created with proper privileges, so replace it in previous command.

Et voilà! Quantum GIS can connect to PostgreSQL server.

Source: https://github.com/mattt/PostgresApp/issues/43

Answer (score 13):

You should verify that you can connect using `psql`. Try `psql -U username -h localhost dbname`. It should prompt for a password then connect. Run `SELECT postgis_version();` to verify that PostGIS is active in the database.

If you can connect but `SELECT postgis_version()` reports an error, PostGIS isn't installed in the database:

> ERROR:  function postgis_version() does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT postgis_version();

*Other solution:*

```
SELECT * FROM Postgis_lib_version();
```

If you want also to see the version of PostGIS and the version number of the libraries GEOS and Proj4 just change `lib` to `Full`.

If you get the above error, then presuming you're running PostGIS 2.0 on PostgreSQL 9.1 or above, connect as user `postgres` and run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`. Eg:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost dbname -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis;'
```

You might also need to install some of the extras, like the PostGIS topology support:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

or the legacy support script, which isn't packaged as an extension and must be sourced:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost dbname -f /path/to/postgis-2.0/legacy.sql
```

See [the PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions).

If you *can't* connect to the DB, it's probably a `pg_hba.conf` issue, failure to create the DB or user, etc. Hard to say without error messages and log contents.